# Graphic Card Drivers Installation in Lubuntu 12.10?

Tags: ati, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I am using Lubuntu 12.10, I want install the drivers for my hybrid graphic card because my laptop fan is always running and produces great amount of heat.

Graphic Card Specification:-

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Caicos [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
```

Well, I followed this [Correct Way to install ATI Video Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)

I got some errors; please find fglrx-install.log:-

```
ankit@ankit-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/tmp$ tail -1000  /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
Uninstalling any previously installed drivers.

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.98/source ->
                 /usr/src/fglrx-8.98

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
cd /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.98/build; sh make.sh --nohints --uname_r=3.5.0-17-generic --norootcheck.....(bad exit status: 1)
[Error] Kernel Module : Failed to build fglrx-8.98 with DKMS
[Error] Kernel Module : Removing fglrx-8.98 from DKMS

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 8.98
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
```

Comment: Install the beta 12.11 driver.With the hd 5670 card I had to skip driver 12.10 completely and install the beta 12.11.In Ubuntu 12.10 ati 12.10 driver was incompatible with unity and after login compiz would crash.

Comment: the installation didn't worked out for me and my graphics was broken. I had to uninstall the faulty driver from CLI to get back to GUI.